# Vowels and consecutive consonants

Tags: word, knowledge

Replace X, Y and Z with three different words to form a meaningful sentence:

> ***In 15th century Europe, the people of the city X experienced the flow of Y whenever a Z performed.***

The three words should satisfy the following conditions:

- X = Anagram of (2 vowels + a set of 3 consecutive consonants).
- Y = Anagram of (2 vowels + a set of 3 consecutive consonants).
- Z = Anagram of (2 vowels + the set of 3 consecutive consonants used in X + the set of 3 consecutive consonants used in Y).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 15th century Europe, the people of the city X

> MILAN - consecutive lmn

experienced the flow of Y

> TEARS - consecutive rst

whenever a Z performed.

> MINSTREL - lmn and rst